# Hash function for binary matrices (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, hash

I am working with big binary 2D matrices that are stored in a vector and every time a new matrix is obtained it is added to this vector, that can reach sizes of about 500 or 1000 elements. What I ask is if there is a more efficient way to store this matrices, maybe with a hash function. When there is a coincidence of two elements in the vector what I need is their position in the vector, not the matrix itself. I am working with Matlab.

this is executed after a new matrix is obtained:

```
states = [states new_state];
for i = 1:size(states,3)-1
    if isequal(states(:,:,end), states(:,:,i))
        found = 1;
        num = size(states,3) - i;
    break
    end
end
```

matrices are binary:

```
new_state = [1 0 0 0; 0 0 0 1; 1 1 0 1; 1 1 0 0];
```

Comment: please post some example code and data; are you essentially having a 3D matrix storing 2D entries? and you want to check if a given entry already exists?

Comment: well good thing about binary is that everything else is represented as binary in a computer. So each of your entries can be represented with a string or an integer;) You can store the integers instead and comparison would be much more faster.

Comment: Have you looked into using [sparse matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html)? You could also just store the locations of the `1` values in a vector.

Comment: are your 2D matrices only `4x4` elements? do you just want to count how often a given matrix occured?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I am researching which one is the most efficient. I work with matrices of 10x10, 30x30, 60x60... but in every execution of the program the size is defined first and not changed (elements in states have the same dimension) . I just want to check the first time a coincidence occurs. The functions works well, i just want to make it more efficient.